# c# : set timer before loop, break the loop when timer has gone for 2min

Tags: c#, timer

I am quite new to C# and I have never used timers before.
I want to run a code in a while loop for 150 seconds. My idea is to set a timer before a while loop that will be turned off after 150 seconds. I have set a boolean exitFlag that is false by default and when the timer goes off it sets it to true.

```
public static System.Timers.Timer DL_stuckTimer;
static int secondleft = 150 ; 
static bool exitFlag = false;

public static void SetTimer()
{
    // Create a timer with a two second interval.
    DL_stuckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000); //tick every 2 second
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    DL_stuckTimer.Elapsed += DL_stuckTimerEvent;
    DL_stuckTimer.AutoReset = true;
    DL_stuckTimer.Enabled = true;
}

/*** Timer that goes off after 2.5 second and will tell the down
**/
public static void DL_stuckTimerEvent(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    if (secondleft == 0)
    {
        DL_stuckTimer.Stop();
        exitFlag = true;
    }
    secondleft -= 2;
}

SetTimer();

do{ 
    //some code here
} while (!exitFlag);
```

This doesn't work . What am I doing wrong. It looks like the timer never goes on at all.

Comment: Use a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and check [Elapsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) property to see how many seconds passed.

Comment: Your code is working for me as it is!

Comment: You don't need the exitFlag though, just check `secondLeft > 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alessandro mentioned, you could use a Stopwatch instead:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        while(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 150000)
        {
            //Do stuff for 150 seconds.
            Thread.Sleep(2000); //Wait 2 seconds before the next iteration/tick.
        }
        sw.Stop(); //150 seconds is over.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Alessandro. Why do I need to add Thread.Sleep(2000) into the code?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the *actual problem*: it seems that you want to perform a *long process* which you want to terminate after 2 minutes if it hasn't been completed.
This is the kind of problem that can be solved with `Task`s:

```
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  ... 

  // 2 minutes = 2 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds
  using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2 * 60 * 1000)) {
    CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

    try {
      Task task = Task.Run(() => {
        //TODO: put relevant code here 
        ...

        // Cancellation is a cooperative, that's why do not forget to check the token 
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
        ... 
        }, 
      token);

      await task; 
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) {
      // Task has been cancelled due to timeout
      //TODO: put relevant code here 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you . It is good to know about the existence of  CancellationToken. I am going to go for the stopwatch option

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `CancellationToken` rather than a timer to do this.

Then you can create a `CancellationTokenSource` which will automatically cancel after a specified time.

Inside your loop, instead of checking an exit flag, you would check `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`.

A full compilable console app example looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150));

            Console.WriteLine("Started at time " + DateTime.Now);
            SomeMethod(cancellationSource.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Finiehd at time " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        static void SomeMethod(CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10); // Some code goes here.
            }
            while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested);
        }
    }
}
```

An advantage of doing it this way is that it is how Task-based cancellation works, and you can pass other kinds of cancellation tokens in if you want to cancel it another way.

You could also change your busy-loop so that it only did something every, say, 500ms, but will still exit the loop as quickly as possible when the cancellation token is signalled.

To do that you would use the `CancellationToken.WaitOne()` method as follows:

```
static void SomeMethod(CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    do
    {
        // Do something every 500 ms.
    }
    while (!cancellation.WaitHandle.WaitOne(500)); // Wait up 500ms, but return immediatly if signalled.
}
```